# In WPF, how do I handle modifier keys that are pressed after a key is held down in a KeyDown event?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a WPF window that I allow the user to move around by pressing the arrow keys. I've done this by hooking into the KeyDown event:

```
<Window ... KeyDown="Window_OnKeyDown">
```

One press of an arrow key will move the window 1 pixel. Obviously, this is pretty slow, so I also allow the user to hold the shift key to move the window around faster, 5 pixels at a time:

```
private void Window_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var key = e.Key;
    var pixelAmount = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift ? 5 : 1;

    switch (key)
    {
        case Key.Up:
            Top = Top - pixelAmount;
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            Top = Top + pixelAmount;
            break;
        case Key.Left:
            Left = Left - pixelAmount;
            break;
        case Key.Right:
            Left = Left + pixelAmount;
            break;
    }
}
```

This code works great if the user presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> followed by an arrow key. Problem is, this doesn't work if the user is holding down an arrow key first, then presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> to speed up the movement. This is because the `Window_OnKeyDown()` now thinks that <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the active key, and the switch statement is run against the Shift key rather than the already-pressed arrow key. Does anyone know how I can fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses the Shift key after the arrow key, e.Key will change to shift and hence this code will not work. Only solution I can think of is using

```
 bool Shift = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
```

and to get the arrow key also, you can use Keyboard.IsKeyDown(), example Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up)

Comment: Hey Manish, I've tried this and although it works mostly as expected, there's a slight delay the moment you hit the shift key. When you press the shift key, the OS detects it as a new key press, and then applies the key repeat delay to it. This results in the window immediately moving 5 pixels, and then the window does not move until the key repeat delay has passed. If you push shift rapidly in succession, this leads to a strange behavior where it looks like the window only moves whenever you push the shift key while you hold down the arrow key.